# javax.ws.rs.NotSupportedException: Could not find message body reader for type: class com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition

Tags: java, web-services, jersey

I have the following web service which is supposed to get a file through a HTML form and save it somewhere on the server.

```
@Path("/dv")
public class Uploader {

    @POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadFile(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream stream, @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetails) {
        FileOperations fo = new FileOperations(stream); // My own class

        try {
            fo.saveToFile(fileDetails.getFileName());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return Response.status(200).entity("").build();
    }
}
```

The HTML form is something like this.

```
<form name="upload-form" method="post" action="http://localhost:18080/dv/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Whenever I upload a file through this form, I get a error

```
javax.ws.rs.NotSupportedException: Could not find message body reader for type: class com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition of content type: multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryHvAymGjNVVEB1VWa
```

Here is the stacktrace

```
javax.ws.rs.NotSupportedException: Could not find message body reader for type: class com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition of content type: multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryHvAymGjNVVEB1VWa
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ServerReaderInterceptorContext.throwReaderNotFound(ServerReaderInterceptorContext.java:52)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.getReader(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:73)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:50)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPDecodingInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(GZIPDecodingInterceptor.java:59)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:53)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:150)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.injectArguments(MethodInjectorImpl.java:88)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:111)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:280)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:234)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:221)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:356)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invokePropagateNotFound(SynchronousDispatcher.java:217)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:224)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:62)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.marmotta.platform.core.servlet.MarmottaResourceFilter$LMFFilterChain.doFilter(MarmottaResourceFilter.java:189)
        at org.apache.marmotta.platform.core.filters.ModuleResourceFilter.doFilter(ModuleResourceFilter.java:169)
```

The issue is that I don't understand what is the problem here. I have changed the @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA) to @Consumes("multipart/form-data") but I get the same error.

The browser sends the HTTP packet with the following Content-Type

```
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryHvAymGjNVVEB1VWa
```

And I get a 415 response from the server

```
415 Unsupported Media Type
```

If it helps, I am using Google Chrome.

Comment: From the stacktrace, you seem to be using RESTeasy, not Jersey. See the [documentation for RESTeasy](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.12.Final/userguide/html/Multipart.html). Here's [the dependency](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-multipart-provider) you'll need

Comment: The FormDataContentDisposition class that is throwing the error is from jersey-contrib.

Comment: It not the Jersey class throwing the exception. Its RESTeasy telling you it doesn't support the Jersey type.   Look at the documentation I linked to for its multipart support. You will not be using Jersey components. You can completely get rid of the Jersey dependency

Comment: Why is it even calling the resteasy libraries? The FormDataContentDisposition should not call the resteasy libraries, right?

Comment: RESTeasy is a complete JAX-RS implementation, just as Jersey is. If you have no idea you are using RESTeasy, my guess is you are using Wildfly/JBoss, which uses RESTeasy as its JAX-RS implementation. You may have Jersey dependencies in your project. But Jersey definitely is not being used, RESTeasy is.

Comment: Yes, using the RESTeasy libraries works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[peeskillet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2587435/peeskillet) was correct. I was using the incorrect dependencies. I updated my pom.xml file to include the RESTEasy jars and it started to work.

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
     <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
</dependency>
```